# Premake4: How to set mac os x xcode C++ project to have option "build active configuration only" active?

Tags: c++, xcode, lua, projects-and-solutions, premake

Problem: when you do not specify that option xcode project tries to build all it can (in my case not only i386 but also some other archs which I do not have library's for and I do not need.)

Current solution - open generated xcode project and set that option in all configurations.

Desired solution - I need to set that option inside premake script.

Question - how to do such much desired thing?

Answer (score 2):

The premake stable bitbucket repo now does this by default for debug configurations.
https://bitbucket.org/premake/premake-stable/changeset/da9d0562b09c

Answer (score 1):

If you really only want i386 (32 bits), then I guess this is what you'd need in your Premake script:

```
platforms { "x32" }
```

You probably had this until now:

```
platforms { "native", "universal" }
```

Which on virtually every Intel Mac means x64 when going native and x32 + x64 when going universal.

Comment: Tested - does not work( (I tried both -platform=universal32 and  --platform=x32 )